# Extracting and assigning polyline attributes by multiple polygon boundaries (ArcGIS)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I have a polygon shapefile containing many (200+) polygons, and a polyline shapefile representing river channels. I wish to add an attribute field to my polygon shapefile of the sum of polyline lengths contained within each individual polygon, with the ultimate goal of finding a drainage density distribution for the polygon population.

I'm sure this can be accomplished with a script, but I have zero experience with python.

Is there a combination of tools or attribute table edits I can make to accomplish this?

I'm using ArcMap 10.2

Comment: Make sure polygon has unique id. Intersect both, output - line in home database. Use summary statistics, polygon I'd case field, total length. Transfer results to polygon s using join.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to @FelixIP's suggestion is to use the spatial join tool. I think @FelixIP's method is more robust to when your data is not well aligned such that you have lines crossing boundaries. The Intersect tool would essentially cookie cut these into their respective catchments.

If you have high confidence that you river lines are actually *completely* within their respective catchment polygons (not an unreasonable demand in hydrology, but often not the case!) then you could do all this in one tool.

When you set up the spatial join tool you can do useful summing and aggregation in the field mapping, something which is often overlooked. So in the screen shot I am joining rivers to catchments, creating a new catchment layer and the output will contain the catchment ID and the sum of lengths of polylines.

[image: Spatial Join Tool]